# In C# how do I take a csv and seperate data into two tables depending on if the data is line data or header data

Tags: c#, csv, datatable

I am trying to do the following but am really struggling on coming up with the solution. Please help.

I have a CSV file and this file has data related to invoices from an accounting system.

An invoice can have what I define as header and line data.

Header data is your fields like customer name, reference, document date etc.
Line data is repetitive and can be your items/service and prices.

These two types of data are mixed together in a single line.

For example the 3 lines below represent a single invoice:

```
Line1: Customer Name, reference, document date, item1 price1
Line2: Customer Name, reference, document date, item2 price2
Line3: Customer Name, reference, document date, item3 price3
```

I want to put the line data into 1 data table and the header in another. However as the above example has 3 lines the header data will be repeated 3 times. how do I add the data into the header table and prevent duplication.

---

Edit

Hi guys. Sorry, my explanation was poor. Here is an example:

Some data:

```
Customer1, INV-184691035,Item1, 10.00
Customer1, INV-184691035,Item2, 20.00
Customer1, INV-184691035,Item3, 30.00
Customer2, INV-184691034,Item1, 10.00
Customer2, INV-184691034,Item2, 20.00
Customer2, INV-184691034,Item3, 30.00
```

I want to spilt this data like this into 2 tables:

Header

```
Customer1|INV-184691035
Customer2|INV-184691034
```

Lines

```
INV-184691035 |Item1 |10.00
INV-184691035 |Item2 |20.00
INV-184691035 |Item3 |30.00
INV-184691034 |Item1 |10.00
INV-184691034 |Item2 |20.00
INV-184691034 |Item3 |30.00
```

Does this make sense?

Comment: Please add more lines to this example file with random data, and ideally post some code you already tried.

Comment: Will suggest you to post more data from csv and output expected.

Comment: Is the CSV file you want to read ordered? Can you safely assume it will first contain all items for customer 1, followed by customer 2 etc? If so, it's just a matter of keeping track when the customer changes while processing the lines.

Answer (score 0):

So you are looking for a way to parse this csv into to tables, one containing the header info and one containing the line data, right?

First read the csv line by line with something like:

```
using(StreamReader SR = new StreamReader(path2file)){
line = SR.ReadLine();
var entries = line.Split(',');
//now move the elements of entries to the table where they belong, entries should be an array
}
```

After this reading, loop through the table containing the headers and remove duplicate entries.
Is that, what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Just needed to think out loud a bit I guess :)

Below selects distinct values based on specific field

```
DataTable dt2 = dt.DefaultView.ToTable(true, "Test");

        foreach (DataRow r in dt2.Rows)
        {
           Console.WriteLine( r["Test"].ToString());

           
        }
```